# Use WaitForSeconds for timing recorded commands

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

What I'm trying to do is a system to replay a list of commands I previously recorded. The list I use contains a class with the command and the time that was recorded (with Time.time), in this way I can decide when to play each command in sequence (for example I execute the first command at 1 second after I press record, and the second command at 5 seconds, in this way when I want to replay the commands they will be replayed waiting the exact seconds).

When I replay the command I used a coroutine with WaitForSeconds, but I discover because is frame rate dependent If the command ends at the middle of the frame the time starts from a cumulative delay (the wait time of the command plus the offset extra to finish the frame) and because this I tried to build something that predicts this problem, but when I replay the commands, the result is a slowdown replay.

```cs
private IEnumerator ExecuteBodyAnimation(List<UserBodyRecord> bodyAnimations)
{
    // Prevent multiple calls
    if (IsAnimationPlaying)
        yield break;

    IsAnimationPlaying = true;

    float extraTime = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < bodyAnimations.Count; i++)
    {
        // Exit if we want to stop the animation sequence
        if (!IsAnimationPlaying)
            break;

        int currIndex = i,
            nextIndex = i;

        // Prevent OutOfRangeException
        if (currIndex < bodyAnimations.Count - 1)
            nextIndex++;

        UserBodyRecord currBodyAnimation = bodyAnimations[currIndex],
            nextBodyAnimation = bodyAnimations[nextIndex];

        // Calculate the time difference between the current time recorded animation and the next one recorded
        float currentAnimTime = currBodyAnimation.timeRecorded;
        float nextAnimTime = nextBodyAnimation.timeRecorded;
        float differenceTime = nextAnimTime - currentAnimTime;

        // Send the body pose list to the provider
        bodyProvider.SetBodyPose(currBodyAnimation.humanPoses);

        float lastRealTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;

        // Wait the time between animations
        yield return new WaitUntil(() =>
        {
            // Exit if we want to
            if (!IsAnimationPlaying)
                return true;

            // Calculate how much time has passed since we are waiting
            float counterTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup - lastRealTime;

            // Add the extra time exceeded from last animation frame
            counterTime += extraTime;

            if (counterTime > differenceTime)
            {
                // Get the extra time
                extraTime = counterTime - differenceTime;

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    // Wait a bit before stop the animation
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayBeforeStopAnimation);

}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not WaitForSeconds(counterTime)?

Comment: either way in a frame-based application you will always have only the precision of frames -> about 17ms for 60 F/s. So it is always possible that you would only need to wait 1ms more but you end up waiting the entire frame => 16ms too much

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I know the answer but you can use :

```
float time = TIME_TO_WAIT;

while(time > 0)
{
time -= Time.deltaTime;
yield return null;
}
```

Comment: This is basically the same, except you don't calculate the extra time to complete the frame. Please see the derHugo's comment under my answer to having a better understanding. :)